# Universal classes to store values

Tags: c#, .net

In project I often use "containers" that store different number of values that have various types.
For example for 2 and 3 values:

```
class Nodes2<K, V> {
        public K Key { get; set; }
        public V Value { get; set; }
    }
class Nodes3<T1, T2, T3> {
        public T1 Value1 { get; set; }
        public T2 Value2 { get; set; }
        public T3 Value3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I use them in collections:

```
List<Nodes3<int, string, double>> descriptions = new List<Nodes3<int, string, double>>();
```

That well suites for simple cases, when there is no neсessity for create individual class for every such case.

So, the question is: are there in .NET built-in classes that can hold values like in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are. For key-values you have [`Dictionary<K,V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For node holders, you have [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (All the way up to 8 elements). Although a bit cumbersome (IMO), you can use them an access your items via `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.

[image: Tuples]

And you use them like this:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create("Hello", 0);
var hello = tuple.Item1;
var zero = tuple.Item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with it's implementations with extra generic type parameters. (`Tuple<T>`, `Tuple<T1, T2>`, etc.). `Tuple` is available from .NET 4.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384265(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var tuple1 = Tuple.Create(12);
Console.WriteLine(tuple1.Item1)
```

And:

```
var tuple2 = Tuple.Create("New York", 32.68);
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", tuple2.Item1, tuple2.Item2);
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a class made for this [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
List<Tuple<int, string, double>> lists = new List<Tuple<int, string, double>>();
lists.Add(Tuple.Create<int, string, double>(5, "string", 10d));
```